# rspec - Check if array contains element with specified ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

My controller method returns an array and I intend to check if an element with specific ID is included, something like:

```
expect(json_resp["animals"]).to contain_element_with_attribute(:id => 4)
```

Comment: could you explicitly state your question please? I read rspec has an `have_attributes` matcher, but we may need to see your rspec version

Comment: `expect(json_resp["animals"].map { |a| a["id"]}).to include(4)` OR `expect(json_resp["animals"].find { |a| a["id"] == 4}).to be_present`

Comment: `expect(json_resp["animals"].any? { |anim| anim['id'] == 4 }).to be true`

Answer (score 4):

As your variable name mentions JSON, I assume you have an array of hashes. In that case, you can use a double `include`:

```
expect(json_resp["animals"]).to include(include("id" => 4))
```

The outer call says the array is expected to contain an element that matches its parameter; the inner one then describes how to match that element: here, by doing another `include` match on a hash.

(Note I've assumed your hash has string keys, again because JSON; you'll need to use whichever is right for your data.)

---

If your array contains regular classes instead, you can still use `include` for the array, but then `have_attributes` for the object inside:

```
expect(json_resp["animals"]).to include(have_attributes(id: 4))
```

Comment: The `include(include())` is very smart!

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to understand what you're asking.

Returns an array of what? Hashes? Objects?

My assumption is that you wish to assert one of the hashes or objects must have a value of four at the id key.

You can use the RSpec Collection membership matcher:

```
expect(actual).to include(expected)
```

In conjunction with the `pluck` or `map` command (depending on what's being returned, I don't actually know what your situation is).

```
let(:result) { json_resp['animals'].pluck(:id) }
# OR
let(:result) { json_resp['animals'].map { |element| element.fetch(:id) }


it 'returns an object with an id value of 4' do
  expect(result).to include(4)
end
```